# If two matrices have the same diagonal entries in any basis basis, are they the same?

Tags: matrices, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices, change-of-basis

I have two $n \times n$ Hermitian matrices $A$ and $B$.
No matter the basis, the diagonal entries of $A$ and $B$ are always the same. Specifically, I mean that if I pick a basis I will observe that the diagonals of $A$ and $B$ are identical and if I perform a unitary transform $U$ the diagonals of the transformed matrices will still be the equivalent.

Is it then true that $A$ and $B$ are the same matrix, i.e. $A_{i,j} = B_{i,j}$ for any $i,j = 1,...,n$?

Comment: Yes. This condition is equivalent to $\langle v, Av \rangle = \langle v, Bv \rangle$ for all $v$, which gives $\langle v, (A-B)v \rangle = 0$ for all $v$. What do you know about matrices having this property?

Comment: Okay I think I see. So we can clearly say that the matrix (A-B) has a diagonal of 0s in every basis. Yet (A-B) is diagonalizable as it is Hermitian due to the Hermiticity of A and B. Hence there exists a basis in which (A-B) is just the zero matrix and so (A-B) is just the zero matrix in every basis, which means A = B?

Comment: Yes, that's right. (Also I misspoke slightly about the equivalence above; that's the condition we get for orthonormal bases, which is already enough to conclude. For general bases the condition is different.)